# How to change request method in ngResource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, ngresource

How modify `save` method for put, if `id` specified and post if not?

I mean:

```
Posts.save({id: 1, content: "..."}) // PUT /posts/1
Posts.save({content: "..."}) // POST /posts
```

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#creating-a-custom-put-request).  Angular's documentation does a great job of showing how to complete common tasks and even shows how to properly unit test.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you cannot do that in normal way. If you want to update just create your own update function in resource like:

```
app.factory('Posts', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/posts/:id', null,
    {
        'update': { method:'PUT' }
    });
}]);
```

[Here is document.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)